# Web Api returning result of other endpoint

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to return the result of another API; 
I try doing it via RestSharp but the following code doesn't seem to work

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReports()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("reports", Method.GET)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };
        var response = _restClient.Execute<List<Report>> (request);

        return Json(response.Data);
    }
```

This returns `null` but on the response.Content there is a string of my json data

and this will probably won't return a 404/500/... whatever the other api trows when not a 200

*note: the reason why this needs to be 1-on-1; 
this api is externally availible, but we can't access the databases on the external api, so we have an internal api that CAN access them. So the external api just works as a proxy*

**UPDATE**

This code returns the data as is, but this will always return a 200, so is there an automated way to return the StatusCode?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @smoksnes: good point, added the info

Comment: So what response do you get when you browse to the url in a browser? What's the status code? Do you need any authentication? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: it also a good idea to show _restClient code as well, and define where do you receive null

Comment: Is `Execute(...)` internally an `async` api call? If yes, need to `await` the result??

Comment: @SivaGopal the call is sync (you can execute an async if you want)

Comment: @Kiwi Did you try any other overload(if exist) that return response as `string`? If the string has JSON as expected, then problem could be casting to `List<Report>`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to

```
return response.Data;
```

and not

```
return response.Content;
```

Comment: This will most likely not work since `List<Report>` (which `response.Data` is) cannot be casted directly to `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: And I can confirm this doesn't work, not the IHttpActionResult, but just my response.data is null

Comment: Yes, @smoksnes you are correct - i must edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> This returns null but on the response.Content there is a string of my
>   json data

It sounds as you're using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) and got a serialization issue, so I'm throwing out a guess here... If `Content` got some value, but `Data` didn't it's often the result of a deserialization going bad.

Make sure that your json can be deserialized into `List<Report>`.

Try to manually deserialize it:

```
var response = _restClient.Execute<List<Report>> (request);
List<Report> myList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Report>>(response.Content);
```

or

```
List<Report> myList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Report>>(response.Content);
```

If `myList` is `null`, there's something wrong in either your model or in the json.

Otherwise, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324526/restsharp-not-deserializing-json-object-list-always-null), regarding `ContentType`.

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
```